# Text being pasted in the wrong order over SSH to Mysql

Tags: mysql, ssh, terminal

I'm not sure if this is a Mysql problem or an SSH problem.  However the issue does not happen when using another terminal program such as nano or a bash script.

I have a mysqldump file containing a bunch of lines that look like

```
INSERT INTO `issues` VALUES (10,'2010-06-21 16:16:08','2010-08-31 11:4...
```

with a lot of different entries (the lines are really long).  I'm trying to paste it into my terminal to insert this data into a remote database, but when I paste, it seems to do it in pieces, inserting the chunks out of order.  Here is an example post-mangling:

```
','May 2011',8,45);','April 2011',7,45),(21,'2011-05-09 09:31:28','2011-05-09 09:31:28','2011-05-12 08:48:16','','March 2011',6,45),(20,'2011-04-07 13:45:14','2011-04-07 13:45:14','2011-04-13 16:00:28','','February 2011',5,45),(19,'2011-03-03 13:36:26','2011-03-03 13:36:26','2011-03-10 08:34:19','','December 2010',4,45),(18,'2011-02-01 13:43:16','2011-02-01 13:43:16','2011-02-15 11:22:09','','November 2010',3,45),(17,'2010-12-07 12:04:53','2010-12-07 12:04:53','2010-12-09 10:00:02','','October 2010',2,45),(16,'2010-11-05 13:04:06','2010-11-05 13:04:06','2010-11-15 11:29:29','','September 2010',1,45),(14,'2010-10-05 08:58:27','2010-10-11 13:28:54','2010-10-12 07:21:20','INSERT INTO `issues` VALUES (10,'2010-06-21 16:16:08','2010-08-31 11:44:18','2010-10-11 12:33:46','\0','June 2010',0,45),(11,'2010-06-24 15:13:00','2010-06-24 15:13:22',NULL,'\0','May 2010',0,45),(12,'2010-08-25 12:47:42','2010-08-31 11:44:02','2010-10-11 12:33:59','
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and a workaround?  I've tried assuming it's a display issue and inserting it anyway but that is a no-go.  It seems it really is out of order.  I'm using 10.6.6 Snow Leopard & Apple's terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Also acceptable is an alternative way to do this, as long as I can use it just as universally as SSH / terminal.  Obviously gui tools can do stuff like this but I like the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue with pasting to both mysql and bash over ssh. The culprit was Unicode characters which got interpreted as control characters.

**Symptoms:** When pasting the text, the insert position would move back to pos 1 several times, seemingly randomly, without starting a new line, and then some new text would be inserted or some already pasted text would be overwritten, resulting in garbled mess.

**Cause:** It turned out that the text to paste had some unicode dash-like characters in them where dashes should be, and these were interpreted by bash and mysql as kind of control characters to move the insert column position.

So make sure your text does not contain unwanted characters before pasting.

**Test:** A good test for me has been to open vi (via ssh or not), go into insert mode (press "i") and insert (press Shift+Insert). It will display Unicode characters broken up into Unicode sequences.

**Example:** My text to paste started like this:

```
mysqldump –-opt –-no-create-db
```

Pasting this into bash or mysql via ssh resulted in:

```
--no-create-dbopt mysqldump
```

Pasting this into vi made the bad dash-like characters visible, resulting in:

```
mysqldump �~@~S-opt �~@~S-no-create-db
```

Means the first dash of every option was the wrong character. I corrected them and now everything worked fine:

```
mysqldump --opt --no-create-db
```

Comment: I ended up saving it to a text file, transferring it, and running it remotely.  However I think this was most likely the culprit.  If you are using TextMate, you can fix this by pressing Control+Command+T and selecting 'Transliterate Word/Selection to ASCII'.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do:

```
ssh hostname mysqldump database | mysql localdatabase
```

And just do the whole thing in one command.

You can of course add various options to the dump command to skip table drop and creation or other things you don't need.

Comment: The issue with this scenario is that I'm changing some table/column names and other select pieces of data in the process as I write the 'v2' of this software.  I already have the dump modified so I need to be able to just paste it in, or as a last resort upload the text file

Comment: @Brandon Well you can redirect the ssh output to a file locally (so you don't have to download a file from the server). Then modify it locally. Also, check out the command `replace` (part of MySql oddly enough), you can pipe through it to change things.

Comment: I edited the file to my liking and then just uploaded it and piped it back in with cat data.sql | mysql database_a.  Still looking for that final solution though.

Comment: @Brandon try copy/pasting in smaller chunks. Also report the bug to whoever makes your terminal program.

Comment: The thing is I can paste over SSH to nano and bash and it works fine.  The problem only happens with mysql, and only over SSH (no problems with my local mysql).  The workaround is barely more work so it's not really a major issue but I'm still curious.